# Ignore file with similar name using regex

Tags: regex

I have a problem using regex
I have a folder that contains 3 files

```
 Test.log 
 Test.log.1
 Test.log.2
```

I want to catch only the test.log file
I tried a lot of combinations like:

```
Test.log
^Test.log
Test.log[^0-3]
```

Etc...
What can I do?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
Test.log$
```

`$` means end of string.

Your three matches didn't suffice because

1. `Test.log` = anything that contains *Test.log*
2. `^Test.log` = anything that starts with *Test.log*
3. `Test.log[^0-3]` = anything that contains *Test.log*, followed by something that isn't `0`, `1`, `2`, or `3`. However, in this case the next character that you didn't want was the literal dot.

Another alternative if you want to expand on your last solution is to use [negative lookahead](http://www.regular-expressions.info/lookaround.html):

```
Test.log(?!\.[0-3])
```

Comment: The alternative still matches the word `Testalog` due to the unescaped `.` character.

Comment: @Jamesking56, which isn't a part of the original problem. If we want to be absolutely restrictive, the solution should be `^Test\.log$`

Comment: still makes the regex incorrect for what the OP asked for.

Comment: @Jamesking56, no it doesn't. What OP asked was "I have these three files, I want to match this one, but not those other two. This is what I have tried, where do I go from here?"